# How to construct an array of incrementing subsets in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, functional-programming, subset

In Matlab, say you have a large vector X

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 1000]
```

How would you select an array of K element subsets with incrementing indices? (No for loops please).

```
k = 100; % 100 element subsets
Y = foo(X,k);

>> Y = 
        1   2   3 ... 100
      101 102 103 ... 200
      201 202 203 ... 300
       .   .   .  ...  . 
       .   .   .  ...  .
       .   .   .  ...  .
      901 902 903 ... 1000
```

Thanks

-----Update--------

Thanks for the quick reply.  I hate it when ask stupid questions.

Now, I have a more challenging one (what I really wanted to know).
Given:

```
X = [1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 1000];
k = 900;
```

How do you produce?

```
Y = foo(X,k);

>> Y = 1   2   3 ... 900
       2   3   4 ... 901
       3   4   5 ... 902
       .   .   . ...  .
       .   .   . ...  .
       .   .   . ...  .
      100 101 102... 1000
```

Thanks again

Comment: Updated the question.  Thanks to Luis and the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy: use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
X = 1:1000;
k = 100;
Y = reshape(X,k,[]).';
```

Or, if you have the Communications Toolbox, you can use [`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html):

```
Y = vec2mat(X,k);
```

Comment: What can I say? ["You're right. When you're right, you're right, and you're right!"](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Chinatown_(film)). This was an easy one... :)

Comment: @chappjc Very easy, yes. I didn't know that quote! :-)

Comment: It came right to mind when I read this Q&A... Chinatown. Seriously though, I tried to come up with a clever alternative, but this just seems like one of those cases where there's just one sensible solution.  Maybe someone will prove me wrong?

Comment: @chappjc I bet you could do it with `accumarray`! :-D